# Trouble with Monotouch Bindings to Cordova (NSInvalidArgumentException)

Tags: c#, ios, cordova, xamarin.ios

I'm building an app that will use a combination of MonoTouch (Xamarin.iOS) and Cordova (PhoneGap). The UI will be primarily made using Cordova, and our business logic will be primarily written in MonoTouch.

I've found a [guide that describes this scenario](http://scott.blomqui.st/2012/08/embedding-cordova-phonegap-in-monotouch-apps/), so I know that this is possible, and the author has added a [Cordova Binding to their fork of the monotouch-bindings project](https://github.com/sblom/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Cordova/Binding).

Unfortunately, when I attempted to create single view project using the bindings, I started to run into problems almost immediately. I build the dll for this using the make file in the provided Cordova Library, and I Added to the `ViewDidLoad` method in the simple view controller in my test app called`MyViewController`. Here is my source

```
public class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    private CDVViewController cdv;

    public MyViewController()
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        View.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        View.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;

        cdv = new CDVViewController();

        RectangleF rect = new RectangleF (0, 0, 320, 480);

        CDV.View.Frame = rect;

        View.AddSubview(cdv.View);
    }
}
```

When I construct the `CDVViewController`, I get the following exception:

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSCFArray dictionaryWithLowercaseKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc892680
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:IntPtr_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr)
  at CordovaIOS.CDVViewController..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at <Project_name>.MyViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x00043] in /Users/jstarke/tmp/<Project_name>/MyViewController.cs:32
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend  (intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible () [0x00010] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIWindow.g.cs:126
  at <Project_name>.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00031] in /Users/jstarke/tmp/<Project_name>/AppDelegate.cs:23
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at <Project_name>.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/jstarke/tmp/<Project_name>/Main.cs:17
```

My research into this issue so far has showed me that this is almost certainly a binding problem. I don't know a lot about bindings yet, but I'm trying to learn, and any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Just to reiterate, the binding I'm using, found from here: https://github.com/sblom/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Cordova/Binding

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/z5MrloZGol4) it's a linker/loader problem.

The link that thread refers to is dead, but it looks like the doc also available here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html

Comment: Thanks Rolf. I had a look at that document, "CordovaLib sub-project" section, point 14, as the thread you referenced mentions. 

I'm a little confused. These instructions seem really specific to making an objective C sub project. You understand I'm trying to make a MonoTouch Binding for this right? I checked that the frameworks referenced in that document are in the LinkWith Frameworks clause, and they seem to be there fine.

Comment: @JamieStarke: I do understand that you're trying to make a Xamarin.iOS Binding for this, my point is really that other people (using pure Objective-C) has run into the same issue, so it is not Xamarin.iOS-specific. However you do need to "port" the Objective-C instructions to the equivalent way of doing it in a Xamarin.iOS Binding. Maybe first try to make a complete Objective-C sample and then go from there?

Comment: Any idea how specific the bindings have to be. I did find, when going through the bindings mentioned above that there were a few issues with referencing methods, and properties that no longer exist in the current headers. Perhaps it's not the entire problem, but it might add to it?

Comment: @JamieStarke: I believe you need to link with PhoneGap too (this is the method not found: https://github.com/lopper/PhoneGap_Cordova/blob/1bf3688902c24c582986ce2ff51908aa6c2342b8/PhoneGapLib/Classes/NSDictionary%2BLowercaseKeys.m)

Comment: Thanks Rolf, I think I've figured out the problem. I had grabbed a copy of Cordova 2.5, and the bindings apparently made against the cordova incubator < 1.9 version. When I attempted to run their make, it would pull down the latest from the repo, and build against that, but the headers appear to have changed since then, no longer having a supportsOrientation, for example` (https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVViewController.h  https://github.com/sblom/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/Cordova/Binding/Cordova.cs). I'll try to write up this evening.

Comment: There was also big changes to PhoneGap since then too, like the way the configs are handled, which threw a big red herring in at the very beginning, and attempting to build a project from scratch in XCode taught me that. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

So as embarassing as this is, I have to admit that I think this was a PEBKAC (Problem Exists Between Keyboard and Chair) problem.

The tutorial that I was following ([here](http://scott.blomqui.st/2012/08/embedding-cordova-phonegap-in-monotouch-apps/)) was actually dealing with an older version of Cordova, but the make file that the author provided would actually pull down the head of Cordova repo to build the bindings.

In all actuality though, this was a red herring, and the real problem was a user (me) problem. I had checked out the most recent version of Cordova, and used that to set up a sample project as per the author's instructions, and when I got to copying over the config.plist (which wasn't there), I mistakenly thought it was just renamed to a different name, and copied that file over instead. When none of the plug-ins were available, the system would crash with the above error message.

I believe it was in Cordova 2.1, but it was definitely by 2.3, the config.plist was removed, and replaced with a config.xml. The bindings did need a few minor updates, but I don't believe that was causing my errors.